# Building CEGUI Dependencies on Mac OS X

Tags: xcode, macos, cegui

I am trying to build cegui on Mac OS X 10.9.4. First, I am building the dependencies from [here](http://static.cegui.org.uk/docs/0.8.3/downloading.html#dl_deps).
I generate the Xcode project files without any problems using cmake. When I try to build the project using the ALL_BUILD target, it fails to build the IL library. [image]
[image]

I have an endian.h file at **/usr/include/machine/** and **/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.9.sdk/usr/include/machine**. I tried adding these paths to the header search path in Xcode but the error remains.